# C# Silverlight: How to get ID from within Silverlight using asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, silverlight

Withing a Silverlight Application, how does one get the ID from the URL when using MVC given the URL in the standard MVC Format {controller}/{action}/{id}

Is there anything MVC specific or does one need to parse this URL 'manually'?

Comment: Do you mean "How to access the id value in the controller" or "How to pass the extacted value to the silverlight app"?

Comment: Yes, the ID from the controller, we currently just look at the URL querystring values. Can Silverlight access the controller data directly...new to Silverlight and MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that's simple, either look in Request.Params["id"] or - and that's more ellegant - add a argument with the name "id" to you Controller method (case does not matter).

```
public void Index(string id) { }
```

Works even for more complex objects, the MVC does a good job in retrieving the information and matching it to the arguments of the controller method.

```
public class Data {
  public string ID { get; set; }
}

public void Index(Data data) {
  // data.id should be set
}
```

Silverlight runs on the client, therefore it cannot access the values on the server. However, the sever can pass the info to the client.

Comment: Do you mean adding this in the Controller and then specifiy this on the View in the object tag that holds the Silverlight app?

Comment: That would be one way. Another could be storing it on the server, and then silverlight pulling it from there.